# Who is Jason Punyon and why is he a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators

[Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6/jason-punyon).  I was under the impression that after we held the moderator elections, all previous moderators would lose their moderator status.

Comment: [Well... he's an SO associate.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-hires-in-new-york/)

Comment: Ah.  So SO associates automatically have moderator status?

Comment: Dunno. But he's not the only one, e.g. [Geoff Dalgas](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/2), [balpha](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/3), [Emmett](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/7)...

Comment: @J.M. Have they *always* been moderators?

Comment: I'll add to my Christmas wish list that this be a bug somewhere...

Comment: If you take a peek at their associated accounts, they "moderate" the other SE sites as well...

Comment: @Mariano:  Yes I've always been a moderator here.  I'm guessing it wouldn't matter if I was de-moderatored, because if I had to do something, I'd just go to the database.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A Christmas shout-out from the math crew.  My dreams have never come truer :)

Scared I'm going to meddle in your fiefdom? Don't worry, my moderation philosophy on the sites that aren't SO is pretty much live and let live.  All of the StackExchange sites have their own communities and I tend to respect that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Jason.  I just wasn't quite sure what was happening here.

Comment: @Qiaochu: No problem, and thanks for all your contributions to our little family here.

Answer (score 9):

SO employees ("associates") have diamond status on all SE sites.

Comment: Just to clarify: we have a diamond if we've had need of it. I don't currently have a diamond *here* for example, but I do in many places.